# Find all values $k$ such that the set $S = \{x^3+x+1, x^3−x^2+1, x^3+k x^2+k x\}$ is linearly independent in $P$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Matrix is
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
x^3 & x & 1 \\
x^3 & -x^2 & 1 \\
x^3 & kx^2 & kx
\end{pmatrix}
$$ 
I reduced it down to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & x + x^2 & 0 \\
x^3 & -x^2 & 1 \\
0 & k & kx - 1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
but I'm stuck at this point.  Any advice or hints?

Comment: Your question is unclear: What is $P$ and why do some $x$ have indices and some not?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik the numbers following the $x$'s are likely exponents.

Comment: @Dave I edited to reflect that, but there are some $x_2$s and $x_3$s and some $x$s without index.

Comment: sorry i didn't finish writing the question. P should be P3(R).

Comment: Which are the polynomial with real coefficients and have degree 3 or less?

Comment: Set up your matrix so terms of the same power are in the same column!

Answer (score 2):

Think of the basis vectors $x, x^2, x^3, 1$ then the matrix is 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & k & k & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then find the $k$ which do not make its rows linearly dependent.

Comment: And the constant?

Comment: @jobe : Good catch! corrected. :-)